# Azure DevOps Classic Pipeline "ref variable"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have classic pipeline in Azure. The pipeline is pointing to release/qa branch. I want to point to release/1.1.

Is there a way to reference "branch_name" as a variable in classic pipeline.

of course, It can be changed in when we click on Run pipeline. But I don't want to change the all the time in all the pipeline.

I have around 20+ pipeline, If I add and ref the variables as a branch name, I don't change in future. I can just modify the value of the varible.

Thanks in advance.

I did try add the varible in library section and linked it in the pipeline. But I don't have option to reference in get sources task in classic pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to start pipelines manually, you should see the option to select for which branch (tag or commit) you wish to start the pipeline:

[image]

Note, that you can setup "continuous integration" in the Trigger part of the classic pipeline and branch filter to include release/* (or even just * and press enter). It will start on any code change in included branches, on the triggering branch.